# MUX chips only happy with one of the inputs

Tags: signal, multiplexer, signal-integrity

I have two [MAX4533](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4533.pdf) quad SPDT chips, all outputs are behaving the same.

NOn - a PWM pulse train at 25% generated by an Arduino Mega.

NCn - a 5kHz square wave from a [AD9833](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9833.pdf) signal generator.

Switching signal comes from the Mega very 3 seconds on all 8 switches, eg if all MUX outputs are the PWM signal then 3 seconds later they will (should) be switched over to the 5kHz signal. Schematic for 2 channels shown below, actual circuit has 8 such channels.

MUX & Mega are powered by 0-12 VDC, the signal generators are powerby 0-5.5V VDC via a [buck converter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Power-Module-DC-DC-Supply-Converter/dp/B071ZRXKJY/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2CO5PM6U0B61U&dchild=1&keywords=buck+converter+12v+to+5v&qid=1621351345&sprefix=buck+con%2Caps%2C158&sr=8-3).

[image]

I scoped the AD9833 output & am getting a clear 0-5v square wave at 5kHz & this is showing at all the NC inputs to the MAX4533s.

So when I check the MUX outputs the PWM comes through as expected 0-5v (some noise though) but when it switches to the signal generator output I get a 5kHz signal in the range 0-0.5v.

The switching is happening when expected.

I have used the MAX4533 in a similar circuit before but never had this issue.

What are the possible causes for this behavior?

Comment: Try looking at the power rail of the MUX.

Comment: @Andyaka clean 0-12VDC not a ripple

Comment: Show your schematic.

Comment: @Andyakaadded some more detail in the OP

Answer (score 0):

The AD9833 DAC Vout is only 0.65V max and elsewhere says 0.6V typ with internal 200 ohm load.  You are getting 0.5V which needs to be calibrated or amplified.  Hmm or both.

Comment: The AD9833 gives 5V max if you select square wave, as mentioned in the OP - I've scoped the output to make sure this is the case.

Comment: I wonder what the impedance ratio is of your losses?  < 200 ohm source , 175 ohm switch, no load? Doesn’t add up.

Comment: Check digital output is working and all quad SPDT  pins for same signal. something must be shunting it

Comment: no load but will be going through a buffer before it gets to the load. I get the same behavior on all outputs on both chips, the PWM channel comes through at 0-5V but the 5kHz signal is attenuated down to 0-0.5V. All 5kHz signal inputs 0-5V

Comment: Strange switch attenuation !  mega cannot be using 12V. Ohm’s Law must prevail in the answer

Comment: Vin anywhere between 7 - 12 V for a mega

Comment: You are forgetting the board has down voltage regulator for the Mega.